# GamesClient go wrong only for first match

Tags: google-play-games

I developed a game on andengine, and I have multiple activity.
So I extend BaseGameActivity in menu class, and another basegameactivity that extends SimpleBaseGameActivity from andengine in the game activity.
With this I can login in menu screen and play, unlock achieve etc in game screen.
But I can get game work properly: only the first match go bad.
I get teardown, network not ready for match.
On the second time all go fine.
If I exit game, and return, I get bad response again.

Have you any idea?

I tried everything, also reconnect, and the flow of code is the same, on first like in second or other times.

Thanks.

Comment: You probably need to post some code...

Comment: You are probably logging out when you switch activities. That's how the GPGS API works.

Comment: With the help of  Bruno Oliveira, that made the example ButtonClicker I found that simply I need to update gameplayservice on ADT. It was updated few days ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to the latest SDK and recompiling should solve the problem. Even if you don't recompile, the problem will be fixed soon, but if you want it fixed right away, just recompile.